# Segmentation fault when trying to create multiple threads for file IO:

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, operating-system, semaphore

I am facing a segmentation fault when I run the following program . I
am trying to make a multithreading program which performs 100 times :

1. Open the file.
2. Read the last line of the file (each line contains a number).
3. Add 3 to the number.
4. Append the new number at the end of the file.
5. Close the file.
   The number of threads is specified by the user.
   When I create 2 threads, this code runs correctly, 
   but when I try to create 1 or a number different from 2, 
   it shows segmentation   fault.

I am using a semaphore for synchronization among threads. 
Do you have any idea why this happens ?

*Part of main:*

```c
    for(i=0;i<NumberOfThreads;i++)  {
        if (pthread_create( pid[i], NULL, subthread, NULL ) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create failed with i = %d. errno = %d, %s\n",i, errno, strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<NumberOfThreads;i++)  {
        pthread_join(*pid[i], NULL);
    }   
    return 0;
}

void *subthread(void) {
    int i ;
    int temp ;
    char ch;
    int offset =0 ;
    FILE * fd1 ;
    FILE * fd2 ;
    for(i=0 ;i<100;i++) {
        sem_wait(&sem1);
        fd1 = fopen (NameOfFile,"r");
        fseek (fd1,-2,SEEK_END);
        offset=-2;
        while((ch=getc(fd1)) !='\n')
        {   
            offset=offset-1;
            fseek (fd1,offset,SEEK_END);
        }
        fscanf(fd1,"%d",&temp); 
        fclose(fd1);
        fd2 = fopen (NameOfFile,"a");
        temp=temp+3;
        fprintf(fd2,"\n%d",temp);
              printf("%d\n",temp);
        fclose(fd2);
        sem_post(&sem1);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

This is just a part of the code.

When I run the code and give 1 thread as an input, it shows an segmentation fault. For 2 threads the execution is correct.
For more than 2 threads it shows again segmentation fault

When I try to debug, to see what is causing the segmentation fault, the log says that the function `PTHREAD_CREATE` causes it.

Comment: how is `pid` defined?

Comment: A few quick things I noticed: First of all [`pthread_create`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) *returns* the error, it's not specified to set `errno`. Secondly, if there's an error with `pthread_create`, then the next loop joining the threads will loop over even the uncreated threads. And the probable cause for the crashes: You probably don't make `pid[i]` point anywhere valid (but it's hard to say without a proper [mcve]).

Comment: And reading your thread function, there's other problems. For example [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) is returning an `int`. This is important if you ever want to compare against `EOF`.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt it is defined  " pthread_t * pid[NumberOfThreads+1];"

Comment: @makululaj Are you defining memory for array of pointers?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Regarding the GETC , yes it will return an int. On this case I dont need to check for EOF because I take the cursor to the end of file using FSEEK and than shift it back until if finds the last element not \n

Comment: @kiranBiradar No, right now I am not. I tried to define it as a fixed memory of 100 elements, but it didnt change anything

Comment: in fact you *do* define it as an array of pointers (otherwise it would be `pthread pid[..]`) but I guess the individual pointers `pid[i]` don't point to a valid location.

Answer (score 3):

For `pthread_create()` the pointer passed as first argument must point to a valid location where `pthread_create()` writes thre thread id.
But as you have said in a comment, `pid` is defined as

```
    pthread_t * pid[NumberOfThreads+1];
```

which is an array of pointers that do not point to a valid location initially. They might be NULL or undetermined depending on how the array is defined.

I would suggest you change the definition to

```
   pthread_t pid[NumberOfThreads+1];
```

and call `pthread_create(pid+i,....)` or `pthread_create(&pid[i],...);` and use `pid[i]` instead of `*pid[i]` for other `pthread_...()` calls

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)